# flask wtf SelectField, dynamic input and validation

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask, flask-wtforms

First question: dynamic input into a SelectField (choices), in my Database (sqlite, with SqlAlchemy) I have a Table, and from this table I wont all entries in the choices from the SelectField. As the selected result I need the ID from the entry.

```
foo_id = SelectField('Label', choices=[Foo.query.all()])
```

Second question: If I put this into the SelectField:

```
foo_id = SelectField('Foo', choices=[(1, 'Foo 1'), (2, 'Foo 2')])
```

Every time:

> Not a valid choice

What goes on with the validation?

Thanks for your time, have a nice day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two answers:

1. Use [`wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields.QuerySelectField`](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.4/ext.html#wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields.QuerySelectField)
2. Add a callable `coerce` argument that will coerce the strings you get back from the browser:

   ```
   SelectField('Foo', coerce=int, choices=[(1, 'Foo 1'), (2, 'Foo 2')])
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry for the late feedback. My Laptop had  a hardware-crash...